# JWT Token will not generate on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, jwt

This is super weird. I have everything working when running my Node.js app on the local host. But after deploying to Heroku, it always gives me 400 Bad Request and a blank response body {} . I tested both environments with the same postman request only changing the base URL.

Here's my post method:

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password', 'f_name', 'l_name', 'phone', 'address']);
var user = new User(body);

user.save().then(() => {
  return user.generateAuthToken();
}).then((token) => {
  res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
}).catch((err) => {
  res.status(400).send(err);
});
});
```

Eventually, I saw that whenever I was trying to create a token when posting a new user, my localhost db does work, but no token was created in the Heroku environment.

Which means this function is the most suspicious of all:

```
UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function () {
var user = this;
var access = 'auth';
var token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id.toHexString(), access}, process.env.JWT_SECRET).toString();

user.tokens = user.tokens.concat([{access, token}]);

return user.save().then(() => {
    return token;
}).catch((err) => {
    return err;
});
};
```

What I don't understand is, why would this make any difference in the deployment environment? And how would I ever know what went wrong inside Heroku? When running locally we usually get those error logs, heroku logs doesn't do any good. And although I tried to catch an error and return them, nothing came back to my postman response body.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should set up JWT_SECRET at Heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked if your environment variables set within Heroku are being correctly received and parsed? I noticed that with my deployment, where I was using rsa encryption for my secret, that new lines characters weren't being recognized.

Locally

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAz7pZEypvrFJCDshsbOam\nj9bmy/dXnUOyCo5b3xSvvTNIoFAC5ePXozCD/5Byih1JB6ZYE6OceEW6oArkPzZO\nl8bFBlqV9k30oerMtVei18+CfF/uFLWlJXs9FvXrRTKtsL43OmpLCH3LdzK9/+Zq\nhEx/TShp3JudUWuRW8ALqrBd8QW5CWJHYozYVaIpFzwJ9KW6fJ9GpZfcToCOquLW\no8iINnAovXmvcAtdmzgIqoucD988f9oerll/CubJLy2rOiyeRvsAYouoefoyQZWN\n8IYPlnb5IB6Z7qnVL6rZz44dAjVwS3uARW3lxpfeZn3TN7wpPkBssGBF0OSEHNrX\nVwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

would be logged as

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAz7pZEypvrFJCDshsbOam
j9bmy/dXnUOyCo5b3xSvvTNIoFAC5ePXozCD/5Byih1JB6ZYE6OceEW6oArkPzZO
l8bFBlqV9k30oerMtVei18+CfF/uFLWlJXs9FvXrRTKtsL43OmpLCH3LdzK9/+Zq
hEx/TShp3JudUWuRW8ALqrBd8QW5CWJHYozYVaIpFzwJ9KW6fJ9GpZfcToCOquLW
o8iINnAovXmvcAtdmzgIqoucD988f9oerll/CubJLy2rOiyeRvsAYouoefoyQZWN
8IYPlnb5IB6Z7qnVL6rZz44dAjVwS3uARW3lxpfeZn3TN7wpPkBssGBF0OSEHNrX
VwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

but on Heroku it would be logged exactly as I provided it - everything appearing on one line, including new line characters. Setting my Heroku environment variables with explicit formatting seemed to fix my signing issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the JWT library is not installed in the Heroku environment. Please try doing an `npm install` on the Heroku environment.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but is there a way to do that? I thought the npm packages were automatically installed when I use `git push heroku master`

Comment: I don't think that's not the case. See if you can access your server via SSH. If not, maybe the Heroku CLI tools can help out. 

But if worse comes to worse, include your node_modules to your commit then pull on Heroku. This is highly discouraged but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since this question, but today I had similar issues. On my side it turned out to be the secret that I used for JWT that was in my .env file which is not uploaded to github and deployed on the herokuapp server.
In case if you use any secrets and want to deploy on heroku you can load them in the variables via the heroku cli.
In my case with *heroku config:set JWT_SECRET='mysecret!@'*